# I-Nex not launching

Tags: drivers

Im trying to install i-nex so I can verify that all my hardware is detected by my computer. When ever I try to launch it I get a strange error Directory or file "asound_drivers._get_informations.54 " not found, program had to abort. Ive tryed installing both the daily and the stable version using the install instructions off of the I-nex website.

Whats that even mean?